# How to correctly get and set UIColor for UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I'm trying to change a `UIView`'s `backgroundColor` based on its current color. E.g. say MyView is now red, on touch I want to make it blue and vice versa. But I noticed I cannot get the correct name of the `UIColor` to check the current color.

As an example, if I do:

```
if MyView.backgroundColor == .systemRed {
        print("Red")
    } else {
        print("Not red")
    }
```

This will always print "Not red", even if I explicitly set `MyView.backgroundColor = .systemRed`

When I check the color being used:

```
print("Color = \(MyView.backgroundColor)")
```

It prints: `[...] name = systemRedColor`

But when I change `.systemRed` to `.systemRedColor`, it gives the error

```
'systemRedColor' has been renamed to 'systemRed'
```

and I'm back at where I started.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing? How do I correctly read and set the `backgroundColor` of `UIView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.systemRed` is one of the dynamic system colours that will be displayed differently depending on the view's current trait condition *(i.e. Dark Mode / Light Mode)*.  Therefore you need to access the current color using the `.resolvedColor(with traitCollection:)` function.

In **Light Mode**, `systemRed` will display as:
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.231373 0.188235 1
R255 G59 B48

In **Dark Mode**, `systemRed` will display as:
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.270588 0.227451 1
R255 G69 B58

```
if view.backgroundColor?.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection) == UIColor.systemRed.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection) {
    print("true")
}
```

This will work with both dynamic and standard `UIColor`'s.

---

You could also make an extension on `UIColor` to do this

```
extension UIColor {
    class func compare(_ colorA: UIColor?, with colorB: UIColor?, in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        colorA?.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection) == colorB?.resolvedColor(with: view.traitCollection)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if UIColor.compare(self.view.backgroundColor, with: .systemRed, in: view) {
    print("true")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
self.bgView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
 print("self.bgView.backgroundColor")

   if self.bgView.backgroundColor!.isEqual(UIColor.red){
      print("Red")
   } else {
   print("No Red")
 }
 print(self.bgView.backgroundColor)
```

//it will print Red