# How to get explicitly light or dark color from ColorSet?

Tags: swift, uicolor, ios-darkmode

Using `UIColor.init(named: "customColorSet")` it is no problem to get color from ColorSet which matches the current `userInterfaceStyle`.

**However, how can I get a specific color from the color set, e.g. the light or dark color?**

I tried using `UIColor.init(named: "customColorSet", in: nil, compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light))` but it doed not seem to work, because still the color matching the current `userInterfaceStyle` is returned (dark in my case).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760612/2303865

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `UIColor.resolvedColor(with:)`

Tested:

```
let color = UIColor(named: "Color")?.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light))
let rgb = color!.cgColor.components
```

Comment: This didn't work for me when initializing the `UIColor` with a SwiftUI `Color`  For whatever reason I consistently get the light mode color in this situation.

Comment: I'm trying this too with a colour that SwiftUI has loaded and it's also returning the same colour regardless of the user interface style.